# Excel Macro: Paste Link run time Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

Need a simple way of performing Paste-Link of copied cells.
The way I would like it to function is:

1. User copies cell or range of cells.
2. User move the blank area of worksheet where data is to be copied.
3. User activates macro that performs Paste-Link function.

I thought it would be a simple record macro of Paste-Link.
The Macro created was:

```
Sub PasteLink()
' Paste Link function
      ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
 End Sub
```

When I run the macro it gives an error message:

> run-time error '1004':
>   Paste method of Worksheet class failed

Comment: You need to copy something before you run that code. Otherwise you cannot paste anything. • Please tell what you copied. Is it in the same workbook? Is it in another workbook? • Your code should work if a range was copied before. Note that you need to perform the **copy action right before the paste action**. If you do something else in between like deleting data in a cell, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: All work in the same worksheet. I tried coping both a single cell and a range of cells.
To do the process manually, I would copy the desired cells, move to where I want to paste them and then use paste special to link the cell back to the source. Not a lot of work but I do this a lot.  I thought I could just create a macro that would do the paste special link portion.  E.G. Copy cell, move to new cell, press function key for the macro.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how your code works. You copy a cell (manually) then you move to the cell you want to paste in (manually) and press the button for your code and the link (formula) gets pasted. If you do it like that your code works